# Jad decompile .class file issues - find some unknown characters in private variables

Tags: java, decompiling, decompiler, jad

When I used JAD to decompile .Class Files, the private variables show unknown characters in private variables.
[image]

My command as below:

```
jad.exe -r -ff -d classes -s java classes/**/*.class
```

I have tried other decompilers (CFR,Procyon,Fernflower) and all have similar issue. Have any better way to overwrite these unknown characters to other readability words ?

Comment: It appears that the class was compiled without debug information, so the field names are simply not there in the .class file, hence the auto-generated names. Without any names in the .class file, what "other readability words" would you expect? `a`, `b`, `c`, ... ? How is that any more readable, given that the names are entirely meaningless?

Comment: @Andreas Just want the names can show more readability. If the field is Date Object, expect to show dateVal0 or dateA.

Comment: What is the Java version used to compile the `.class` file?